# Pegar valor de apenas uma variável

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com meu sistema de vendas.
O sistema funciona da seguinte forma, quando eu aperto no botão `+`, ele adiciona o produto ao carrinho, até aí tudo certo, porém, ele está pegando o código de todos produtos os cadastrados. Algum de vocês tem ideia de como resolver isso ? Existe alguma forma de limitar a variável a apenas um valor ?

Script que pesquisa os itens:

```
<?php 
    include "php/conexao.php";

    $cod_produto = "";
    $nome_produto = "";
    $obs_produto = "";
    $valor_produto = "";
    $status_produto = "";
    $cod_categoria = "";

    try {
        $pesquisa = $conexao->query("select * from produto order by 1 desc");

        foreach( $pesquisa as $row ){
            $cod_produto = $row[ '0' ];
            $nome_produto = $row[ '1' ];
            $obs_produto = $row[ '2' ];
            $valor_produto = $row[ '3' ];
            $status_produto = $row[ '4' ];
            $cod_categoria = $row[ '5' ];

            echo '<div class="pizzas">';
            echo '<h4 class="codigo_produto">'.$cod_produto.'</h4>';
            echo '<p class="nome_pizza" ><b>'.$nome_produto.'</b></p>';
            echo '<p class="valor_unitario">R$ '.$valor_produto. '  <button 
            onClick="inserir()">'.$cod_produto.'</button></p>';

            //echo '<h4 class="codigo_produto">'.$cod_produto.'</h4>';
                }

    } catch
        ( PDOExPDOException $erro ){
            echo $erro->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Tenta enviar o código para dentro do inserir(), com ajax acho que seria mais fácil

Comment: apresente o código da função `ìnserir()`